# Programmed UISlider value not changing

Tags: ios, swift, slider, cgrect, sender

My code uses a programmed slider and I want to find the value in the debug section of Xcode. I am not seeing anything in the debug area except for "ben: 0". If I move the slider to the end of the right section it will say "ben" 1" but that is the only values I am see being changed. This is all code so you can just copy into your Xcode project, no storyboard needed.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var move = UISlider()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        [move].forEach({
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            self.view.addSubview($0)
        })

        move.frame = CGRect(x: view.center.x-115, y: view.center.y+200, width: 200, height: 30)
        move.addTarget(self, action: #selector(moveRight), for: .valueChanged)
    }

    @objc func moveRight(_ sender: UISlider) {
        let currentValue = Int(sender.value)

        print("ben:",currentValue)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First**  you need to give that slider positioning constraints like top , leading and width as you set `$0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` which invalidates setting the `frame` otherwise comment it and leave the `frame` line

**Second** default values for the slider's `minimumValue` , `maximumValue` are 0,1 respectively so you need to set them according to what you need

---

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad() 

    self.view.addSubview(move) 
    move.minimumValue = 10 
    move.maximumValue = 50 
    move.frame = CGRect(x: view.center.x-115, y: view.center.y+200, width: 200, height: 30)
    move.addTarget(self, action: #selector(moveRight), for: .valueChanged)
}

@objc func moveRight(_ sender: UISlider) {
    let currentValue = Int(sender.value)

    print("ben:",currentValue)
}
```

Comment: can you write a sample code I will give you the verified answer?